# WPF: Share an observable collection between two windows?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid

I was wondering how I would be able to share an observablecollection between two different WPF windows in the same project. The situation seems easy enough, but I have not yet found a solution.

I have Window1 that has a datagrid that is bound to an obervablecollection like so:

```
        public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _bookLibrary = new ObservableCollection<BOOK>();       
        datagrid.ItemsSource = _bookLibrary;
    }
```

Within Window1, I am able to Add/Remove BOOK objects to/from the _bookLibrary collection and the datagrid updates correctly.

I have another window, Window2. Window2 uses a Service Reference that is also able to generate BOOK objects. I want to be able to add Window2 BOOK objects to the _bookLibrary collection located in Window1 (since Window1 has the "main" datagrid where the entire library is displayed).

I was maybe thinking about using a separate collection for the Window2 BOOK objects and then merge that collection w/ the Window1 collection.

Any ideas / suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to me you have to introduce a Model in your architecture and share that model between the two views. So you just bind in xaml both the view to the same property ( the collection ) of your model.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be another not MVVM way of doing this by using `CollectionViewSource`:

```
<CollectionViewSource 
Source="{Binding Source={x:Static Application.Current}, Path=_BookLibrary}"   
x:Key="Window1View" />

<CollectionViewSource 
Source="{Binding Source={x:Static Application.Current}, Path=_BookLibrary}"
x:Key="Window2View" />
```

Create whatever `ItemsContainer` you want (like `ListBox`) and cite the appropriate collection view:

```
<Window name="Window1">

<ListBox Name="Master" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="8"
ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Window1View}}">
```

...

```
</ListBox>
</Window>
```

Do the same for Window2.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized Im referencing a private object "_NameLibrary" in my 2nd window.  Another easy solution  is to just make a class Library that is public to entire application and procede with creating 2 unique Collection Views